# Url-rewriting with multiple parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

```html
DirectoryIndex /home.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+) product.php?id=$1&product_name=$2 [L,QSA]

 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]



ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
```

I have this .htaccess file when i try this with 1 parameter it works but with 2 it doesnt work and i want to turn this product.php?id=1&p_name=exmpl link into product/1/exmpl with the above code i have to write this product/1/exmpl with my hand

Comment: What do you mean by _“i have to write this product/1/exmpl with my hand”_? Are you talking about what the links in your HTML documents are pointing to? Of course you have to change that yourself. What you have above, is the “other direction” - it manipulates the _requests_ reaching your server, this has nothing to do with what HTML your site outputs to begin with.

Comment: You have only one set of grouping braces in your regular expression, `([0-9]+)`, so that only gets you a `$1` back reference. You need to match a second group of characters to begin with, if you want a `$2` to become available.

Comment: i was talking about the get request after submitting it doesnt redirect to product/1/exmpl it redirects to product.php?id=1&p_name=exmpl so is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Are you talking about submitting a _form_? Then you would have to do an _external_ redirect, in the opposite direction - you need to match the incoming request `product.php?id=1&p_name=exmpl`, and rewrite that to `product/1/exmpl`. (A RewriteRule matches on the path component of the URL only, if you want to match parts of the query string, you need to do that via a RewriteCond.)

Comment: and how am i gonna do that i'm reallyt bad at htaccess codes so if u have guide link for that i'd be appreciate it thanks for ur answers btw

Comment: Do some research, try something, and then report back with the results. https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/301-redirect-query-string or https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString might help get you started.

Comment: thank you i have manged to do it somehow thanks for your interest